# Trello cards seem to be moving themselves into new positions in the list

Tags: trello

I have been organizing a couple lists this morning, and when I move a card, I will notice cards above and below it seem to be changing their position (randomly?) after I drop the one I'm dragging.  Later I'll look and see that several cards are totally our of order.

Is this a known bug?  Does anyone know why this is happening?  I'm using Chrome.